# Broadcasting new npm package versions after publishing?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, npm-publish

We're publishing our npm packages via VSTS and I'd like to send out a notification to our Devs with the new package version.
Is there a standard way of doing this? Preferably I'd like to send the notification via Microsoft Teams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn’t the package event for notification in VSTS, also Microsoft Team doesn’t include package event too.

The workaround is that, you can send email through PowerShell in build/release if you are publishing package through build/release. [Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-5.1)
You also can subscript build/release completed event for the specified build/release definition (can do it in Microsoft Teams), then specified build/release publish package completed, it will send notification.